# How to extract filename from path using regex

Tags: python, regex

I would like to extract a filename from a path using regular expression:

mysting = '/content/drive/My Drive/data/happy (463).jpg'

How do I extract `'happy.jpg'`?

I have tried this: `'[^/]*$'` but the result still includes the number in parenthesis which I do not want: `'happy (463).jpg'`

How could I improve it?

Comment: `'/content/drive/My Drive/data/happy (463).jpg'.split("/")[-1]` if you don't want to use regex. Or better, `'/content/drive/My Drive/data/happy (463).jpg'.split(os.sep)[-1]`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I use javascript.

In javascript case,

```js
const myString="happy (463).jpg";

const result=myString.replace(/\s\(\d*\)/,'');
```

After you split path in slash separator,
you can apply this code.

Comment: I glad to help you. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use 2 capturing groups. In the first group match `/` and capture 1+ word chars in group 1.

Then match 1+ digits between parenthesis and capture `.jpg` asserting the end of the string in group 2.

```
^.*/(\w+)\s*\(\d+\)(\.jpg)$
```

In parts that will match

- `^.*/` Match until last `/`
- `(\w+)` Catpure **group 1**, match 1+ word chars
- `\s*` Match 1+ whitespace chars
- `\(\d+\)` Match 1+ digits between parenthesis
- `(\.jpg)` Capture **group 2**, match `.jpg`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SYlZL0/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/DJhS8k)

Then use group 1 and group 2 in the replacement to get `happy.jpg`

```
import re

regex = r"^.*/(\w+)\s*\(\d+\)(\.jpg)$"
test_str = "/content/drive/My Drive/data/happy (463).jpg"
result = re.sub(regex,  r"\1\2", test_str, 1)

if result:
    print (result)
```

Output

```
happy.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**Without Regex**; `str` methods (`str.partition` and `str.rpartition`):

```
In [185]: filename = mysting.rpartition('/')[-1] 

In [186]: filename 
Out[186]: 'happy (463).jpg'

In [187]: f"{filename.partition(' ')[0]}.{filename.rpartition('.')[-1]}"
Out[187]: 'happy.jpg'
```

---

**With Regex**; `re.sub`:

```
re.sub(r'.*/(?!.*/)([^\s]+)[^.]+(\..*)', r'\1\2', mysting)
```

- `.*/` greedily matches upto last `/`
- The zero-width negative lookahead `(?!.*/)` ensures there is no `/` in anyplace forward
- `([^\s]+)` matches upto the next whitespace and put as the first captured group
- `[^.]+` matches upto next `.`
- `(\..*)` matches a literal `.` followed by any number of characters and put as the second captured group; if you want to match more conservatively like 3 characters or even literal `.jpg` you can do that also
- in the replacement, only the captured groups are used

**Example:**

```
In [183]: mysting = '/content/drive/My Drive/data/happy (463).jpg'

In [184]: re.sub(r'.*/(?!.*/)([^\s]+)[^.]+(\..*)', r'\1\2', mysting)
Out[184]: 'happy.jpg'
```